# Entity Framework takes horribly long to load navigational item

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I recently ran into a problem I cannot seem to fix myself. I am loading a List of raffles ( 2 ). As well as a list of refs connected to users to make the connection between raffles and users n:n. Now if I load the Raffles without the refs, it's very fast. But once I include the ref table, it takes about 14 seconds despite the fact that there are only 2 users and 2 raffles in the database. Any idea what's going on?

Thank you

```
public class Raffle
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<RaffleTicket> RaffleTickets { get; set; }
}


public class RaffleTicket
{
    public Int32 UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public Int32 RaffleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Raffle Raffle { get; set; }
}

return this._Context.Raffles.Include(x => x.RaffleTickets).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you start by showing us the code you're using to load the data?
It's probably also useful to inspect the SQL that Entity Framework generates.

Comment: if you run a direct SQL statement by joining Raffle and RaffleTickets, how long does that take? Do you have proper index setup on the database tables?

Comment: Enable SQL logging and see what sql is being generated ... you can try
context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
And inspect generated sql statements